# How to validate if Chrome is preloading resources hinted in a 103 response?

Tags: google-chrome

I am able to validate that we are returning the expected [HTTP 103 response](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/103):

```
curl -D - https://local.contra.dev:8080/log-in
HTTP/1.1 103 Early Hints
Link: <https://builds.contra.com>; rel="preconnect"; crossorigin
Link: <https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@400;500;600;700;900&display=swap>; rel="preload"; as="font"
Link: </static/assets/entry-client-routing.de82cadc.js>; rel="modulepreload"; as="script"; crossorigin

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
cache-control: no-store
referrer-policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
x-frame-options: sameorigin
content-type: text/html
content-length: 5430
Date: Tue, 26 Jul 2022 19:19:28 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=72
```

However, how do I confirm that [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) (which is [the only browser that supports 103 Early Hints](https://caniuse.com/?search=103)) is taking advantage of these hints?

I don't see anything in Chrome network tab that would indicate that resources are loaded early.

Answer (score 1):

One way to check would be to use the [Performance API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance).

```
performance.getEntriesByName("https://path/to/your/resource")
```

You should see a `PerformanceResourceTiming` object with `initiatorType: "early-hints"` corresponding to your early hinted resource assuming your headers are working. See here: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/early-hints.md#checking-early-hints-preload-is-working.

I've also used network waterfalls in Chrome's devtools which should show the resource being loaded from disk cache with low time to load. Hopefully better support will arrive soon for tracing early hints requests in devtools.

Note that early hints in Chrome *don't work* over HTTP/1.1. https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/early-hints.md#what_s-not-supported